# How to read the content from a C# HttpResponseMessage in javascript?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, csv, export-to-csv

I have a string called csv that is literally just that, things like "name,lastname,age,height,etc"
Then I send it to the backend like this..

```
var csv = exportRequests.GetCSV();
            var filename = string.Format("{0}-{1}-{2:yyyy-MM-dd_hh-mm-ss-tt}.csv", "Request", requestStatus.ToUpperInvariant(), DateTime.Now);              

            var stream = new MemoryStream();
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
            writer.Write(csv);
            writer.Flush();

            var result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                Content = new ByteArrayContent(stream.GetBuffer())
            };
            result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition =
                new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
                {
                    FileName = filename
                };
            result.Content.Headers.ContentType =
                new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/csv");
          
            //var test = new FileDetailViewModel();
            //test.Name = filename;
            //test.Rows = csv;

            return Ok(result);
```

I then read it on the backend, but where is the actual content?? Surely the bytes should be somewhere. The content property only has the headers.. This is taking place on an old system using $.ajax to make the call.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question and add in your code segment (not a screenshot of the code segment).

Comment: The result on the js needs to be a screenshot so you can see the result, but i have pasted in the c# above.

Comment: Did you check your API with tools like Postman or simply requesting data from the url? There you can find if it sends something to the server or not. It must be actually your first step.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think it is possible to read content via `HttpResponseMessage` in JavaScript. You can only download content.

```
public HttpResponseMessage GetCsv()
{
     var csv = exportRequests.GetCSV();
     var filename = string.Format("{0}-{1}-{2:yyyy-MM-dd_hh-mm-ss-tt}.csv", "Request", requestStatus.ToUpperInvariant(), DateTime.Now);              

     var stream = new MemoryStream();
     StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
     writer.Write(csv);
     writer.Flush();

     var result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
     {
        Content = new ByteArrayContent(stream.GetBuffer())
     };
     result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition =
     new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
     {
         FileName = filename
     };
     result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/csv");
      
     return result;   
}
```

download script

```
window.open('/api/controller/GetCsv', '_blank', '');
```

If you want to display `csv` content you can use the following code

```
[HttpPost]
public String GetCsv()
{
    return exportRequests.GetCSV();
}
```

script

```
$('#btngetcsv').click(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "/api/controller/GetCsv",
    data: {},
    type: "Post",
    dataType: "Json",
    success: function(result) {
      var arr = csvToArray(result);
      for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        var name = arr[i].name;
        var lastname = arr[i].lastname;
        //etc...........
      }
    },
    error: function() {
    }
  });
});

function csvToArray(str, delimiter = ",") {
  // slice from start of text to the first \n index
  // use split to create an array from string by delimiter
  const headers = str.slice(0, str.indexOf("\n")).split(delimiter);

  // slice from \n index + 1 to the end of the text
  // use split to create an array of each csv value row
  const rows = str.slice(str.indexOf("\n") + 1).split("\n");

  // Map the rows
  // split values from each row into an array
  // use headers.reduce to create an object
  // object properties derived from headers:values
  // the object passed as an element of the array
  const arr = rows.map(function(row) {
    const values = row.split(delimiter);
    const el = headers.reduce(function(object, header, index) {
      object[header] = values[index];
      return object;
    }, {});
    return el;
  });

  // return the array
  return arr;
}
```